# awk multiple word-regex match from a file

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk

I am trying to use awk for `word-regexp` bt not able to get it for `/` search along with others patterns.

I have below file called `/tmp/fstab` from which i want three regex pattern match `/sap`, `/sap-data` and `/` from the third column as they appeared in but somehow not getting it for `/`.

```
$ cat /tmp/fstab

#
# Created by anaconda on Wed Apr 26 14:50:13 2017
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=90db8951-35c4-4b03-734b-e157a272cf53 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_tmp /tmp xfs defaults,nodev 0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_usr /usr                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_varlog /var/log                xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_varlogaudit /var/log/audit          xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/tmp /var/tmp none defaults,nodev,nosuid,bind 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0

UUID="dddd13632-d6cf-4ed0-89f0-1026ab2f15af" /sap       xfs     defaults        0 1
UUID="7b896cf9-f842-4d3f-ee33-76c01e71aa69" /sap-data   xfs     defaults        0 1
```

### My Result:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /sap|sap-data/  && $3 ~ /xfs/'  /tmp/fstab
UUID="dddd13632-d6cf-4ed0-89f0-1026ab2f15af" /sap       xfs     defaults        0 1
UUID="7b896cf9-f842-4d3f-ee33-76c01e71aa69" /sap-data   xfs     defaults        0 1
```

### My Desired:

```
$ awk '$2 ~ /sap|sap-data/  && $3 ~ /xfs/'  /tmp/fstab
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID="dddd13632-d6cf-4ed0-89f0-1026ab2f15af" /sap       xfs     defaults        0 1
UUID="7b896cf9-f842-4d3f-ee33-76c01e71aa69" /sap-data   xfs     defaults        0 1
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this with an alternation of `/` wrapper around in anchors:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^\/(sap-data|sap)?$/ && $3 ~ /xfs/' /tmp/fstab
```

```
/dev/mapper/vg_system-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID="dddd13632-d6cf-4ed0-89f0-1026ab2f15af" /sap       xfs     defaults        0 1
UUID="7b896cf9-f842-4d3f-ee33-76c01e71aa69" /sap-data   xfs     defaults        0 1
```

---

Regex `^\/(sap-data|sap)?$` matches starting `/` followed by an optional match of `sap-data` or `sap` before end. Optional match of `(...)?` allows it to match just `/` as well.

Comment: I am Just learning through, Is there a another shortest form, sorry for asking too much.

Comment: `awk '$2 ~ /^\/$|sap-data|sap/ && $3 ~ /xfs/'` might be little shorter

Comment: `"^/$|sap(-data)?"` would be shorter too. Not sure how making a script shorter makes it any clearer or simpler though!